# Optimize JavaScript CSS download

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a number of pages for my website all use jQuery and JSON and the same CSS, except for a few pages.  The first page is user login.  As the user will take time to type in his username and password, I want to download all the required JavaScript and CSS files for the entire user session during login.  How can this be done?  The header is the same for all pages.  How do I optimize it?

Comment: Please explain this `for entire user session`

Comment: @user982207 Would you be happy to include jQuery in your page? Ill be able to make my answer easier to follow

Comment: entire session meaining till user doesnt logout..

Comment: @sam yes im using jquery json and googlemaps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My idea would be load in js and css files dynamically after `document.load`. This would not affect the load time of the login page, whilst also caching your js and css files once the user has logged in.

You could also easily change this to `document.ready` if it loads faster for you.

What about something like this?

```
$(document).load(function() {
    function preloadFile(filename, filetype){

        //For javascript files
        if (filetype=="js"){
            var fileref=document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        }

        //For CSS files
        else if (filetype=="css") {
            var fileref=document.createElement("link");
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }

    //Examples of how to use below
    preloadFile("myscript.js", "js"); 
    preloadFile("javascript.php", "js");
    preloadFile("mystyle.css", "css");
});
```

References

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: could give it a try..but what if the css of 2 pages are different..can i download css of future pages during the login itself?

Answer (score 6):

- Add all your css/javascript on your login page.
- Put all your css at the top in HEAD section.
- Put all your Javascripts at the bottom.
- Also make your Javascripts and CSS as external files as they are cached by browser(rather than writing the inline javascript and css
  in the page).
- Minify your Javascript and CSS

**UPDATE 2**

Post loading of JS and CSS could also be done using [YUI GET UTILITY](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/get/)

For more details look at this [Yahoo : Best Practises for Optimizing your WebSite](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/)

Comment: I like how #4 is contradicting #1, #2 and #3

Comment: By putting link to external file, not the actual JS and CSS

Comment: @Anand Interesting edit about YUI Get Utility. I'll be taking a look at that when i have some spare time

Comment: This is actually the correct solution. There is not a need to dynamically (with Javascript) load other javascript if you simply want to put it into the cache. All you have to do is put all the links to the relevant css files (optimally 1) in the header and all the links to the relevant javascript files (optimally 1) just above the closing body tag. See HTML5Boilerplate for examples and explanation.

Comment: @Dwight This would affect the load time of the login page. By loading dynamically it would stop this.

Comment: @Sam Incorrect. The total time will be longer with your solution because while both solutions load all CSS and JS, your solution requires additional JS to do the dynamic loading. Your solution will lead to this: 1. page begins loading. 2. loading page finishes loading. 3. The user is now blocked from doing anything until your script and the rest of the scripts are downloaded and applied to the page. Each time you append a new script to the page it BLOCKS user input until the script is fully loaded and run, which may introduce input glitches. Versus just loading all the scripts at once.

Comment: There are some HTML5 features of the script tag (async and defer) that can help (see: http://www.sitepoint.com/a-detailed-breakdown-of-the-script-tag/ ), but as far as I know, there's no way to simply put a script into the cache without executing it, except perhaps downloading and storing scripts as text into localStorage and then evaling them later. But unless you're building a world-class super-heavy client, I doubt you need to get anywhere near that kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

> i want to download all the required javascript and css files for entire user session during login

```
<title>Login</title>
<script src="foo.js"></script> <!-- This line might be better placed just before </body> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend an asynchronous loader e.g. requireJS.

Once you've created and compressed your javascript and css, assign the loading of it to an event, for instance when the user focuses on the username field.

Facebook uses a similar trick with their typeahead queries: loading data relevant to the user when the search box gains focus.

Comment: (began writing this before Sam's comment, which is similar to what I'm suggesting.)

Comment: I might be wrong, but unless he's using Node, he won't be able to take advantage of the optimization tool in require.js.